# Wifi direct multi hop communication

Tags: android, adhoc, wifi-direct

I'd like to implement p2p communication with multi hop android device. At the first time, I used ad hoc mode in android but when android 4.0 come ad hoc mode is not available anymore. So I'd like to find the new way to implement p2p communication with multi hop in android.
I do some research about this and I found the way to connect devices together is to use WIFI-DIRECT.
I've read a lot about this

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html

In this web site provide API of wifi direct that available to use. 
One of this function that I interest is `"createGroup()"` and `"connect()"`

So I imagine that if I can createGroup and join another group in the same time, I can make it like ad hoc mode.

Is it possible to do that? and if not how can I make it work?
Could you please give me some help or link of some sample tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

Well, in theory it is possible to do what you want, according to Wifi-Alliance. However, the android's implementation of Wifi Direct does not allow for the direct communication between devices, which means that whatever type of message that you need to send it has to pass through the Group Owner. And also by definition ( according to Google's API):

"A p2p group consists of a single group owner and one or more clients. In the case of a group with only two devices, one will be the group owner and the other will be a group client."

This definition basically says to you that: Once you have a device that is a Group Owner, this same device cannot be a client of another group. Not only that but also, once you are connected to a Group as a client, you are not able to connect to another group, and act as a bridge.

Hope this helps you in your project. Cya.